# Is there a formula to count occurrences of a string in another sheet when the string needs to be "looked up" in a different sheet? (Quiz example)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Sorry for poor title wording.

I am keeping track of quiz questions in a Google Spreadsheet. In order to generate question statistics I also keep track of some metadata about each theme in a different sheet. Finally, I want to show theme metadata statistics grouped by each quiz in a different sheet. All data is manually entered, except for the numbers which I want to be generated from a formula. Consider the following:

Sheet name: "Quiz 1"

| Theme | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Super Mario | What is Mario's occupation? | Plumber |
| Call of Duty | What is Soap's real name? | John MacTavish |
| Tunic | What animal is the player? | A fox |

Sheet name: "Themes"

| Theme | Popularity |
| --- | --- |
| Super Mario | Well-known |
| Call of Duty | Well-known |
| Tunic | Unknown |

Sheet name: "Stats"

| Popularity | Quiz #1 |
| --- | --- |
| Unknown | 1 |
| Well-known | 2 |

What is a formula/function I can use to calculate the numbers in the stats sheet?

Edit: Alternatively, would it be easier to group/structure the data differently?

Comment: Question is unclear.  You can Improve it by adding column and row references to your examples and giving a name to each table, then letting us know what a calculation would do.  e. g. In table 3, column 2 I want to calculate how many times value x shows up in table 2 column 4 where it also equals the value in table 1 column 1 but is greater than 7.

Answer (score 0):

- each table in its own sheet
- each table starts at cell A1
- sheet names : "Quiz 1", "Quiz 2", "Stats"

```
# In sheet "Stats":

         A                   B              
   --+------------+------------------------------+-
   1 | Popularity |         Quiz #2              |
   --+------------+------------------------------+-
   2 | Unknown    | =COUNTIF('Quiz 1'!$B$2:B,A2) |
   --+------------+------------------------------+-
   3 | Well-known | =COUNTIF('Quiz 1'!$B$2:B,A3) |
   --+------------+------------------------------+-
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I made an edit to hopefully make it more clear.